# How should I import Design System React css?

Tags: lightning-design-system, node.js, node-salesforce, react

I tried using Lightning Design System React doing what's under the [Getting Started](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/) section.

I've installed the npm modules as explained:

```
npm install @salesforce-ux/design-system @salesforce/design-system-react
```

Then, the code sample is pretty simple:

```
import { Button } from '@salesforce/design-system-react';
<Button label="Hello Button" />
```

However, this does not work as css are not loaded.
What's the best way to import css in my react app ?
Obviously I don't want to reference the node_modules folder, nor do I want to copy/paste the css inside my src folder, but I don't know what's the recommanded way to do it.
I can't find anything under getting started.

Comment: I thought you need a className there as well to reflect the design system class ?

Comment: No, "Button" is a design system react class, and it renders correctly as a button with the correct classes. Just css projects are not part of my project. I can copy paste them, or load directly from node_modules but that does not seem like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your build system looks like. If you are using Webpack to manage your CSS, you could import the path and have Webpack insert the CSS in a bundle. If you are using Create React App, you can follow [these directions](https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/blob/master/docs/create-react-app.md) linked from the Design System React readme and copy the files into public and then modify `index.html` to reference it.

There are many ways to structure an application. Please describe your application in more detail, and hopefully I can be of more help.

There are CSS assets on Platform, too, but I will need to look them up.

Comment: I don't have any build system so far, just experimenting a first react app. I used create react app, but though there would be something better than copy pasting them. I've started using webpack so I'll do what you said. Thanks.

Comment: It comes down to Create React App's webpack config. I don't think the webpack config is set to read CSS from the node_modules folder. It's easily done from an app that you can modify the webpack config, but in order to keep things simply you can't do that in CRA.

Comment: It's still copy and paste, but we'd like to create an npm module for CRA that does the copy and paste for you. https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/issues/1518